# VBA: Defining CurrentChart as the string in a cell

Tags: vba

I'm looking to find a way to set the current chart as whatever I have in a a cell in an array. For example, my array will have Chart_1_4301 as the first listing, and I then want to set the chart, which is also named Chart_1_4301, as the CurrentChart.

Rather than saying

```
If Array_Name(i) = "Chart_1_4301" Then
 'Some sort of code
End If
If Array_Name(i) = "Chart_1_4404" Then
'Some sort of code
End If
If Array_Name(i) = "Chart_1_4552" Then....
```

ect. Is there a way to  set  the CurrentChart as the name of the chart, whose name is stored in a cell?

I just want to say something like: `Set CurrentChart = Array_Name(i)`

I know something like this is possible in MATlab (which is the only other programming I've done) but I don't know the syntax in VBA. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: I am not sure if I have understood what you are asking properly. Charts are a special type of objects (ChartObject) with different properties. One of these properties is the Name, which is a string. You can do CurrentChart.Name = Array_Name(i) (if Array_Name is of type string) but you can only do Set CurrentChart = curChartObject when curChartObject is of ChartObject type; curChartObject might also be an array and then you might do Set CurrentChart = curChartObject(i)... where curChartObject is of type  ChartObject and thus has all the corresponding properties like ChartObject(i).Name

Answer (score 0):

For better assistance, it is helpful to post more of your code.  Varocarbas gave some suggestions, above.

I will give you another suggestion based on a different interpretation of your incomplete question.  Since I do not know what `Type` is the `CurrentChart` (i.e., is it a `ChartObject` or a `Chart`?)

Assuming you're doing some sort of loop/iteration over the array of names, and you want to operate on each chart in sequence:

```
For i = lBound(Array_Name) to UBound(Array_Name)

    Set CurrentChart = ActiveSheet.ChartObjects(Array_Name(i))

Next
```

Comment: Hopefully it makes more sense this way.

If you had to access a lot of different graphs, which don't really have a useful order to them, but they were all named in the same format, eg Chart_####. And you have a combobox, which has #### as output, corresponding to the graph name (eg combobox 1234 should call Chart_1234, combobox 2244 -> Chart_2244) is there a way to say Set CurrentChart= Chart_1234, if combobox = 1234 and Chart_2244 if combobox= 2244 without if statements?

Now I'm cycling through all charts, and checking if the name is the same. Its inefficient.

Comment: No, this does not really clarify anything. YOu haven't answered any of the questions regarding what `Type` of variables, and your use case illustrations are convoluted. Good luck.